# Presentation $\langle x,y\mid x^3=y^3=(xy)^3=1\rangle $ with normal abelian subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, group-presentation

> Let $G$ have the presentation $G=\langle x,y\mid x^3=y^3=(xy)^3=1\rangle $ and let $S=\{xyx,x^2y\}$, $H=\langle\, S\,\rangle $. Prove that $H$ is a normal abelian subgroup of $G$.

That the elements of $S$ commute is easy to see. And then $H$ is abelian. As to $H$ being normal, I think it is enough to prove that given $s\in S$, $x^{-1}sx \in H$ and $y^{-1}sy \in H$. But how do I do it? I have tried but I failed.

Comment: You need to show more. You need to show that $x^{\pm 1}sx^{\mp 1}\in H$ and $y^{\pm 1}sy^{\mp 1}\in H$.

Comment: Alright. Suppose I have  $x^{-1}(xyx)x$ which is equal to $yx^2$. How do I prove it belongs to $H$? I think it's very difficult.

Comment: One thing I could do is to list a good quantity of words in $S$. In that way, perhaps $yx^2$ appears in the list. For instance, the powers of $(xyx)(x^2y)=xy^{-1}$.

Comment: You are right. It can be very difficult to prove that. Have you seen any algorithm any class?

Comment: By you observation $$(xyx)(x^2y)=xy^{-1}\in H.$$
Take its inverse $$(xy^{-1})^{-1}=yx^{-1}=yx^2 \in H $$

Comment: Well, it's a book, A Course in the Theory of Groups, Derek Robinson, 2nd edition, exercise 2.2.4, page 56. It's a book for graduate students, so I don't think  it contains tools to show the normality in the pages that precede page 56.

Comment: Map your group to the group of order 3 (send both $x$ and $y$ to the same generator). Show the kernel is $\langle S\rangle$. Hint: show $\langle S\rangle$ contains $[x,y]=x^2y^2xy$.

Comment: @pigeon: your observation proved to be very useful. I conjugated each element of $S$ each time by $x, x^{-1},y$ and $y^{-1}$ and saw they belonged to $H$. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I will denote the inverse of an element by a prime. So for instance $x':=x^{-1}=x^2$.

We have for the two generators $s=xyx$ and $t=x^2y$ the relations

- $st=(xyx)(x^2y)=xyx^3y=xyy=xy^2$, and
- $ts=(x^2y)(xyx)=x(xy)(xy)(xy)y^2=xy^2$
- so $st=ts$, and
- its inverse is $yx^2$ because of $(xy^2)(yx^2)=x(y^3)x^2=xx^2=1$.

Then there are following relations of conjugation with $x,y$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x'sx &=
x^2\ xyx\ x = yx^2=(st)^{-1}\in \langle S\rangle = H\ ,
\\
y'sy &= y^2\ xyx\ y =yx^2\ (xy)(xy)(xy)=yx^2\in H\ ,
\\
x'tx &=
x^2\ x^2y\ x = xyx = s\in H\ ,
\\
y'ty &= y^2\ x^2y\ y = (y^2x)(xy^2)=t'(st)\in H\ . 
\end{aligned}
$$
Note: If we want to show $xsx'\in H$ explicitly, we may use $xsx'=x'x'sxx=x'(x'sx)x$, etc.

Comment: . . . n i c e . . .